# Only show the content of a clicked header and hide others

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with four headers with id of heading-1, heading-2, heading-3 and heading-4. These headers have contents in div containers with the ids of content-1, content-2, content-3 and content-4 respectively.

The four headings are shown by default but only the contents of "content-1" div is shown while the remaining three containers "content-2", "content-3", and "content-4" are hidden and not displayed.

To NOT display these contents by default, I set their "display" property to "none". To display "content-1", I added class name of "active" which set the "display" property to block.

To give the "heading-1" a green color, I added class name of "active" which set the color to green

The contents of any container "content-1, content-2, content-3 and content-4  should ONLY SHOW when their corresponding headings "heading-1", "heading-2", "heading-3" and "heading-4" is clicked. On clicking it, only the clicked header and its corresponding content container should be given the class names "active" for the color and display styles to be applied respectively.

Only one content and header can be active at a time. If a new header is clicked, the class name "active" should be removed on any header and content that has it and added to the clicked one.

I already wrote out the code for this but it is not scalable and can really get overwhelming when you have lots of headers and contents.

What is the best way/method/code to achieve this solution?

Note: The code should be in VANILLA JavaScript and NOT Jquery.

Thanks.

```js
const headingOne = document.getElementById("heading-1");
const headingTwo = document.getElementById("heading-2");
const headingThree = document.getElementById("heading-3");
const headingFour = document.getElementById("heading-4");

const contentOne = document.getElementById("content-1");
const contentTwo = document.getElementById("content-2");
const contentThree = document.getElementById("content-3");
const contentFour = document.getElementById("content-4");

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target === headingOne) {
    headingOne.classList.add("active");
    headingTwo.classList.remove("active");
    headingThree.classList.remove("active");
    headingFour.classList.remove("active");

    contentOne.classList.add("active");
    contentTwo.classList.remove("active");
    contentThree.classList.remove("active");
    contentFour.classList.remove("active");
  } else if (event.target === headingTwo) {
    headingTwo.classList.add("active");
    headingOne.classList.remove("active");
    headingThree.classList.remove("active");
    headingFour.classList.remove("active");

    contentTwo.classList.add("active");
    contentOne.classList.remove("active");
    contentThree.classList.remove("active");
    contentFour.classList.remove("active");
  } else if (event.target === headingThree) {
    headingThree.classList.add("active");
    headingOne.classList.remove("active");
    headingTwo.classList.remove("active");
    headingFour.classList.remove("active");

    contentThree.classList.add("active");
    contentOne.classList.remove("active");
    contentTwo.classList.remove("active");
    contentFour.classList.remove("active");
  } else if (event.target === headingFour) {
    headingFour.classList.add("active");
    headingOne.classList.remove("active");
    headingThree.classList.remove("active");
    headingTwo.classList.remove("active");

    contentFour.classList.add("active");
    contentOne.classList.remove("active");
    contentThree.classList.remove("active");
    contentTwo.classList.remove("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 140%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heading.active {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Headers/Contents</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box-1">
      <h2 class="heading active" id="heading-1">Heading One</h2>
      <h2 class="heading" id="heading-2"> Heading Two</h2>
      <h2 class="heading" id="heading-3">Heading Three</h2>
      <h2 class="heading" id="heading-4">Heading Four</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box box-2">
      <div class="content active" id="content-1">
        <p>Content One</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content-2">
        <p>Content Two</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content-3">
        <p>Content Three</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="content-4">
        <p>Content Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach to shorten the code , using a common `class` for `heading` and `content` without requiring to set an `id`.

```js
let H2 = document.querySelectorAll(".box-1 h2.heading");
let AllSet = document.querySelectorAll( ".box-2 > div.content,.box-1 h2.heading ");
for (let e of H2) {
  e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let linkedClass = this.classList.item(1);
    toggleActive(linkedClass);
  });
}
function toggleActive(linkedClass) {
  for (let i = 0; i < AllSet.length; i++) {
    AllSet[i].classList.remove("active");
    if (AllSet[i].classList.item(1) == linkedClass) {
      AllSet[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 140%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:0;
}

.heading.active {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.content:nth-child(even){background:#bee}
.content {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: none;
  flex:1;
  background:#eeb
}

.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <h2 class="heading heading-1  active">Heading One</h2>
    <h2 class="heading heading-2"> Heading Two</h2>
    <h2 class="heading heading-3">Heading Three</h2>
    <h2 class="heading heading-4">Heading Four</h2>
    <h2 class="heading heading-5">Heading Five</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-2">
    <div class="content heading-1 active">
      <p>Content One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content heading-2">
      <p>Content Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content heading-3">
      <p>Content Three</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content heading-4">
      <p>Content Four</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content heading-5">
      <p>Content Five</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // If we just clicked on a heading
  if (event.target.classList.contains('heading')) {
    // Extract the number from the id
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
    // Only add the active class on the current heading
    for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
      const heading = headings[i];
      heading.classList[heading === event.target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    }
    // Only add the active class on the current content
    for (let i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      const content = contents[i];
      content.classList[content.id === `content-${id}` ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container{display:flex;max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto;background:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:10px;padding:50px}.heading{font-size:28px;line-height:140%;cursor:pointer}.heading.active{color:green}.box{width:50%}.content{font-size:18px;line-height:25px;display:none}.content.active{display:block}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <title>Headers/Contents</title></head><body> <div class="container"> <div class="box box-1"> <h2 class="heading active" id="heading-1">Heading One</h2> <h2 class="heading" id="heading-2"> Heading Two</h2> <h2 class="heading" id="heading-3">Heading Three</h2> <h2 class="heading" id="heading-4">Heading Four</h2> </div><div class="box box-2"> <div class="content active" id="content-1"> <p>Content One</p></div><div class="content" id="content-2"> <p>Content Two</p></div><div class="content" id="content-3"> <p>Content Three</p></div><div class="content" id="content-4"> <p>Content Four</p></div></div></div><script src="app.js"></script></body></html>
```